# Running a ZendFramework project inside a subdirectory

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a ZendFramework project that I would like to run inside a subdirectory.

Currently my document root is at **/var/www** and the project is at **/var/www/project** with the various folders (*controllers*, *public*, etc.) all within the **project** directory.

I am trying to make it so that all requests from http://webserver/project/* are being passed to the **/var/www/project/public/index.php** file. However, trying to use the following code in **/var/www/project/.htaccess** to pass all requests does not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /project/public/index.php [NC,L]
```

There is also an `.htaccess` file in **/var/www/project/public** that contains exactly the same code, but when loading the **/project** URL I am just presented with a directory index of the project contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd store the project completely separate to the document root, for example `/home/user/projects/project`.

Then, simply symlink `/var/www/project` to `/home/user/projects/project/public`.

Provided you use the BaseUrl view helper for any static asset links (JavaScript, images, CSS, etc), it should work just fine.

**Edit**: Another suggestion is to separate your public directory from the rest of the application.

For example, say your project is in `/home/user/projects/project`, move the contents of your `public` directory to `/var/www/project` and edit `index.php` with the following

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', '/home/user/projects/project/application');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question and the asker has long since figured out his problem but I just ran into it. This is the solution I found that worked the simplest and hopefully anybody else that arrives here will see this.

In your VirtualHost file simply add an Alias right about your  tag to create a VirtualHost file like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user/example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /home/user/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /home/user/example.com/logs/access.log combined

    Alias /zend/albums /home/user/example.com/zf2-tutorial/public 

    <Directory /home/user/example.com/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://localhost"
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Edit: Just figured out you will have to edit your .htaccess (in the *public* directory) to include this line (going with the above example):

```
RewriteBase /zend/albums
```

Here's a pretty good answer by Phil that's similar to mine but he removes his .htaccess files completely and instead puts the rules inside the VirtualHosts file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7563414/1031714

Answer (score -1):

Remove the first RewriteRule: it is saying for all addresses rewrite to nothing (`-`) and stop (`[L]` flag).

**Edit:** This should fits your needs

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !project/public/.*
RewriteRule ^project/(.*)$ project/public/$1 [NC,L]       

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s      
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l      
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d      
RewriteRule ^.*$ /project/public/index.php [NC,L]
```

This rewrites any request to project/ not containing public/ to project/public/.
The next one redirects any call to non existing file or dir to index.php in the same directory.

Comment: No, it says to leave all requests for real files (with size greater than zero), symbolic links and directories alone.

Comment: Yes but when he calls `project/` that is a directory, he got no rewrites so he just end up in `/var/www/project/` instead of `/var/www/project/public`.