# Running Zend Framework from within a folder with .htaccess rules

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Greetings. Basically, I'm trying to run a Zend Framework application (multiple of them, actually) from within folders -- but without specifying the public directory. I know this sounds dirty but I have my reasons so it's outside the scope of my question.

For example, this may be one of my ZF "installs":
http://www.myurl.com/project1/
(Others may be at /project2/, etc.)

I'm using the standard ZF directory structure. I'm also familiar with the various methods of placing an .htaccess in the project folder to redirect traffic to /public/ that is often used for shared hosting environments with Zend Framework -- the problem is that when your project root isn't the base URL, it doesn't seem to work.

Specifically, if I place the following .htaccess file in /project1/

> RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$0 [L]

I get a ZF error page stating:

> Invalid controller specified (project1)

So it seems to think that the folder name is a controller.

I get the same problem if I use the more lengthy solution explained here:
http://www.alberton.info/zend_framework_mod_rewrite_shared_hosting.html

(Obviously, I replace the paths with paths that contain "my" path, ie. /project1/)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not into ZF but you need to tell it somehow that the project root is /project1/. Otherwise it'll use / and /project1/ is then seen as a subpage.

Comment: I think I just had an ah-ha moment with your comment. I use .htaccess on live shared hosting sites to tell it to send traffic from / to /public/ and figured this was the same thing but doing that is actually sending it where it's supposed to go, so I think you're right that this is treated differently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a ZendFramework project inside a subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620010/running-a-zendframework-project-inside-a-subdirectory)

Comment: See my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620010/running-a-zendframework-project-inside-a-subdirectory/5620432#5620432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, my previous answer was boneheaded. Trying a different tack.

A comment on [this post](http://www.papayasoft.com/2010/05/08/zend-framework-shared-hosting/) notes this problem but that it can be handled by setting the `baseUrl` on the app's front controller.

I'd add an entry to `application/configs/application.ini` (probably per environment) and then set it in `Bootstrap`. That should allow the routing to ignore the `/project1/` prefix and focus on the rest of the url.

**Update**

I would set a key like `application.ini`, something like:

```
[production]
settings.baseUrl = "/project1"
```

If this varies on a per-environment basis, then you could add an entry per-environment:

```
[development:production]
settings.baseUrl = "/some/local/url/prefix/project1"
```

Then in `application/Bootstrap.php`, add a method like:

```
protected function _initBaseUrl()
{
    $options = $this->getOptions();
    $baseUrl = isset($options['settings']['baseUrl']) 
        ? $options['settings']['baseUrl']
        : null;  // null tells front controller to use autodiscovery, the default
    $this->bootstrap('frontcontroller');
    $front = $this->getResource('frontcontroller');
    $front->setBaseUrl($baseUrl);
}
```

That oughtta do it.

Comment: I understand the issue per the comment from Eliasdx and I believe you have the same idea here. If you want to suggest a way to access and modify the baseUrl() here I'll go ahead and accept this as I do believe you're correct.

Comment: Looks pretty smooth to me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Following on from David's answer, if you need to NOT rewrite resources in /public do the following

Say you have a project at url domain.com/yourapplication

create /.htaccess like this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule    ^$ public/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

in /application/configs/application.ini add

```
settings.baseUrl = "/yourapplication"
```

in /application/Bootstrap.php add

```
protected function _initBaseUrl()
    {
        $options = $this->getOptions();
        $baseUrl = isset($options['settings']['baseUrl']) 
            ? $options['settings']['baseUrl']
            : null;  // null tells front controller to use autodiscovery, the default
        $this->bootstrap('frontcontroller');
        $front = $this->getResource('frontcontroller');
        $front->setBaseUrl($baseUrl);
    }
```

Now when you go to domain.com/yourapplication in a browser, htaccess will redirect all requests that aren't valid files into domain.com/yourapplication/public and set your front controller to yourapplication.